# Abstract Class vs Interface - Practical Application

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I am learing OOP and I guess I understand Abstract Class, Interface a bit already but I still have problems to apply them.

Interface should be considert for 'has-a' situations. Inheritance should be used in 'is-a' cases.

Now let us say I have the following Classes to build:

*MyExcel:*

- Open(Path)
- Open()
- Save(Path)
- Import(from Array)
- CopyTo(Dataset)

*MyAccess:*

- Open(Path)
- Query(SQL-Command)
- Close()
- CopyTo(Excel)

Let's say the goal is to build flexible code like

```
Dim test as MyDataStream
test = MyAccess
```

to be flexible in the case I want to get data from Access instead of Exel.

I could build an Interface or abstract Class called MyDataStream. Excel and Access would be a DataStream ('Is-A'). On the other side I could say my Excel-Class is defining a contract with the connection class because it wants to have its methods. 
MSDN gives the following decition criteria:

- If you anticipate creating multiple versions of your component,
  create an abstract class.
  -> Yes I do,like a PowerPoint class, a WebService Class and so on. So this point goes for using abstract class.
- Abstract classes should be used primarily for objects that are
  closely related, whereas interfaces are best suited for providing
  common functionality to unrelated classes. -> Acutally my classes just need the same functionality. So this point goes for using an interface.

I am just not sure what I have to choose. MyExcel 'is a' Datastream or MyExcel 'has a' Datastream?

It would be great if anyone could tell me what would be the best choice and why.

Comment: You can put common base functionality in an abstract class, for one thing.  You can't do the same with interfaces.  Beyond that, there's a ton of help for your question [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=abstract+class+vs+interface).  Note that abstract classes are an "is a" relationship, whereas interfaces are more often a "has this" relationship.  Compare Stream vs IEnumerable or IComparable.

Comment: Hello Robert. I wrote the "is-a" "has-a" difference in my post already (did you read it actually?) Thanks for your link I went through the highest rated questions on SO already but I still cannot decide what to do, that is why I opened up this question. I dont think it is an duplicate since this is an individual application of the oop topic.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are looking for, then?  What do you want to know that isn't already adequately covered in the duplicate post, and in the numerous posts in the google search i linked? Did you compare the way Stream is used with the way IComparable is used, like I asked you to?  Filestream is a Stream but List has IEnumerable capability.  Do you see the difference?

Comment: Just because I read 100 books about flying doesnt mean I can fly. I do not want to reinvent the wheel here I just need help applying the concepts I mentioned above. I get your point, I have two good books about oop in front of me but I still cannot find the right approach for my problem. If you think this is not enough specific or reason for a question, feel free to delete the posting.

Comment: Everything you need to know is already in your question, except that you got your examples wrong.  Not quite sure how you managed that.  Ill reopen your questuion, but im not at all sure how we can help you.  Did you check out the difference in usage between Stream and IComparable, like I asked you to?

Comment: It takes some time for me (as a beginner) to understand Stream and IComparable. I will work through it after work. Maybe you're right and due to the examples nobody can help me. I will delete the post if it turns out like that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Despite Harvey's reservations, I wrote an answer anyway as I had a comparable problem last month. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an interface. Inheritance is often used too easily.

As noted on MSDN, if most of what you need is code-reuse, try collecting common functionality in utility classes. This is also known as composition. If you need to make a small bit of behaviour more specific (NetworkFileSaver vs HarddriveFileSaver), an abstract base class **might** be your best bet, also known as inheritance.

Suppose you were to add a `MyDataStream` abstract base class to only MyExcel and a WebService. Later on, you will need a `FancyTextEditor` feature, in both MyExcel and MyPowerpoint. How will you solve that? You cannot make it an abstract base class, as MyExcel will need to have both base classes. You cannot make it a base class, inheriting from `MyDataStream`, as not all `MyDataStream`s are `FancyTextEditor`s.

For more on this topic, Google on 'inheritance vs composition'.

Comment: That is a good point. Thank you Rogier. I will use an interface and see how it works.